# Magento core_config_data row update using install script

Tags: magento, installation

How can I change value in a row of *core_config_data* table using install script?

Comment: Why would you wanna do that? Rather give the full scenario and there might be better way to tackle the problem.

Comment: I'd be interested in this as well, the main reason to accommodate for this would be staging / and local development environments.   Anytime I bring a production database into staging, I always have to manually change the web/secure web/unsecure urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes ,can do this by using below code

```
$Switch = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
/*
*turns notice on
*/
$oSwitch ->saveConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', "http://127.0.0.1/magento1702/", 'default', 0);
/*
*turns notice off
*/
$switch ->saveConfig('web/secure/base_url', "http://127.0.0.1/magento1702/", 'default', 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! This worked for me Amit! Yes Rob, the main reason I want to do this is because of switching into staging and not wanting to manually change data in  core_config_data table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento way instead of custom code.
For example:

```
$valueToInsert = 'Custom url, or another value';
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->update($this->getTable('core_config_data'),
        array('value' => $valueToInsert),
        $installer->getConnection()->quoteInto('path=?', 'web/secure/base_url')
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

Where first parameter of **update()** function is table name, the second one is array 'column name' => 'your value', and the last parameter is WHERE clause. In this case we are using prepare statement in function **quoteInto()**.
More detail for **update()** finction you can find in **Varien/Db/Adapter/Interface.php**